# Finding the jsPlumb connection between two ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I am trying to remove the connection between two html elements. I have the ids of both elements, but I do not know how to find the connection in the jsPlumb instance that combines the two. How can I find the connection between two ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all Connections from "d1" and detach them

`jsPlumb.select({source:"d1"}).detach();`

`select` can take the following parameters :

```
[scope] String | String optional

[source] String | String optional

[target] String | String optional

[connections] Connection[] optional
an existing list of Connections. If you supply this, 'source' and 'target' will be ignored.
```

References :

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/querying.html#select
https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_select